# struck.pack equivalent in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

i'm trying to translate a python code to ruby, however I do not get the same value

python:

```
timestamp = 1523966261 #int(time.time())
math = timestamp // 30
time_buffer = struct.pack('>Q',math)
```

> output : b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x07!\x1b'

ruby:

```
timestamp =  1523966261 # Time.new.to_i
math = timestamp / 30
time_buffer =[math].pack('Q>')
```

> output : \x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\a!\e

where did I go wrong ?

Comment: It has to be `Q>` in Ruby

Comment: @Stefan fixed that the output got reversed, however still not equal, I'll edit this in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, the flags are specified *after* the type:

```
timestamp =  1523966261
math = timestamp / 30
time_buffer = [math].pack('Q>')
#=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\a!\e"
```

Note that:

```
"\a" == "\x07" #=> true
"\e" == "\x1b" #=> true
```